# Strange vine growing in garden

Tags: identification

Can anyone help on identifying this vine?
[image]

Comment: what part of the world?

Answer (score 1):

It's Basella rubra, a vine commonly known as Malabar spinach. It would have had small, white or pink flowers, and these have now become the green seeds you're seeing on the stem, which then turn black. It's not actually a true spinach, but the leaves are edible and can be used in salads. It's a perennial plant, but only in areas which are frost free with warm winters. More info below, though the image isn't great

[Malabar Spinach plant](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/vegetables/malabar-spinach/growing-malabar-spinach.htm)

Here's a better picture of a [Malabar Spinach plant.](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/1318/#b)

Comment: This is probably a superfluous comment, but while watching a cooking show last night, I saw this malabar spinach, that's not really a spinach, for the first time. Now I see it's an interesting plant. I can't grow it where I live, but it's fun to get a chance to learn about it.

Comment: @Sue I think it can be grown as an annual even in the UK, though I've not checked. Bet I've eaten it without knowing, its often used in Indian curries instead of spinach, and I often eat ready made sag aloo...